# Using a function to create a class: passing arguments

Tags: python, class, design-patterns

```
def cclass(arg1):
...     if True:
...         class klass (object):
...             print arg1
...             def __init__(self,arg1):
...                 self.arg1=arg1
...             def klassfunc(self):
...                 arg2=self.arg1
...                 print arg2
...     return klass()
```

This code naturally produces an error message:

```
>>> test=cclass('astring')
astring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<interactive input>", line 10, in cclass
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

My question is: how should I pass the functions arg1 on to the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it into the constructor, like you would do for any other python class. :-)

```
return klass(arg1)
```

Comment: @Pieters: thanks. As this is fully educational, is there some other way?

Comment: What other way are you looking for, what's the use case?

Comment: Just playing around. As i can also pass arg1 in as a simple variable,I probably got possible use cases covered. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: @root you could make `arg1` a default parameter: `__init__(self, arg=arg1)`